# ¿Cómo usar Retrofit?

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit

Estoy empezando con android y estoy consumiendo en servicio REST que eh creado, El REST funciona correctamente en una app WEB pero con android me estoy dificultando. Me estoy guiando de la página de [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) (2.4.0) y bueno tengo estos detalles.

Este es mi interfaz

```
public interface ClienteService {

    @GET("prueba/{id}")
    Call<List<Cliente>> listRepos(@Path("id") String user);

}
```

Este es mi MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView resultado;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        resultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResultado);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://10.51.1.136:100/api/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        ClienteService servicio = retrofit.create(ClienteService.class);

        Call<List<Cliente>> repos = servicio.listRepos("1");
        resultado.setText(repos.clone().request().toString());
    }
}
```

Esto me muestra la app Movil, tanto en emulador como en Móvil Físico.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto me muestra la web.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probablemente el inconveniente este aquí. No se como usarlo y en realidad estuve probando aquí.

```
resultado.setText(repos.clone().request().toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de agregar la linea:

```
    Call<List<Cliente>> repos = servicio.listRepos("1");
```

Necesitas hacer el CallBack para hacer la conexión y solo esperar la respuesta del servidor:

```
    repos.enqueue(new Callback<List<Cliente>>(){
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<List<Cliente>> call, Response<String> response){
           //Recorrer la lista de tus clientes
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<List<Cliente>> call, Throwable t){
           //Tratar el error con la conexion
       }
    });
```

Comment: Solo tuve que agregarle esto dentro del "onResponse"
-> resultado.setText(response.body().get(0).getApellido()); <- y todo ok